# Referencing Excel Useform from .NET

Tags: .net, excel, vb.net, userform

Is there a way to reference Excel userform from outside?

I am working on an automation and I need to fill out an Excel form from VB.NET. I can get the running Excel application with `Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")`, but I did not find out on how to get the userform.

I open the userform by calling a function which contains the `userform.Show` method, like this `exApp.Run("Sheet4.cmdOptions_Click")` (exApp is a reference to the Excel application).

I am not the owner of the Excel file, I am not able to do any changes in it.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to access userform from vb.net, so I injected a macro into the workbook and executed that. All of it runs as a `Task` to avoid getting stuck if macro fails.
Here's an example:

```
Dim sb As StringBuilder
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(
Sub()
    sb.AppendLine("Sub openForm()")
    sb.AppendLine("userForm.Show 0") ' opens the form
    sb.AppendLine("userForm.chkDSAlerts = False") ' sets checkbox value
    sb.AppendLine("userForm.txtA.Value = 25")
    sb.AppendLine("userForm.txtD.Value = 60")
    sb.AppendLine("userForm.cmdApply.Value = True") ' clicks Apply button
    sb.AppendLine("End Sub")

    exApp.WorkBooks(1).VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1).CodeModule.AddFromString(sb.ToString()) ' creates new module with the created macro in it
    exApp.Run("openForm") ' executes the inserted macro
End Sub)
```